# Display First 10 Records in RecyclerView through API in retrofit.

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview, retrofit, retrofit2

I am displaying 20 records in recyclerView through api in retrofit. Now I want to add Load More button at bottom of screen and display next 10. Can you give me an idea how can I proceed further.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39558704/pagination-while-scrolling-recycler-view-to-the-top.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement endless list with RecyclerView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26543131/how-to-implement-endless-list-with-recyclerview)