# Android Recyclerview listen to pull up and pull down for pagination

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I want to achieve pagination in the recycler view (not endless scroll).

Here is the first image:

[image: image 1]

When I scroll up I want to listen for that event and go to the next page, when I scroll down I want to listen for that event and go to the previous page

See the below video for a scroll up event
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwNGR.jpg

See the below video for a scroll down event
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAjRJ.jpg

Comment: have u tried searching this ? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36127734/detect-when-recyclerview-reaches-the-bottom-most-position-while-scrolling) is  how u find bottom end and for top end u will be at 0th position and the first completely visible item with 0th one  something like [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39558704/pagination-while-scrolling-recycler-view-to-the-top).

Comment: it does  not work

Comment: @enou plus instead of just saying it does not work, please provide attempts of what you have tried so that the community may help you

Comment: What I tried is


    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

        if (!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1) && newState == SCOLL_STATE_DRAGGING) {
            Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "Reached last and still dragging", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }


but this will trigger when the user scrolled fastly and reached the bottom

I need to detect Recyclerview Drag Even When reached the end
https://imgur.com/a/XamC8Np

Comment: @enou plus, please include what you tried in your question, not as a comment